# Could not connect to host, SoapFault exception after some requests

Tags: php, laravel, soap, soap-client, lumen

I am connecting to a webservice to get some data. I have a queue of requests with about 200K jobs and a worker is handling it. Process time is 2-3 calls per second. After about 500-1000 calls, it starts getting SoapFault exception with this message: `Could not connect to host`. Even when I get this error I am able to ping the webservice server properly.

When I disable soap cache, the problem is still there but the error changes to `Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://thewebservice.com/method/Service.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity`

Connection code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://thewebservice.com/method/Service.asmx?WSDL');
$response = $client->__soapCall('method name', $parameters)
```

I work with:

- PHP 7.0.11
- Lumen (5.2.9) (Laravel Components 5.2.*)

Comment: Are you creating a new SoapClient instance for every call? This will keep a connection open for every new call.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem was too many open connections at the same time. I fixed it by `keep_alive` option:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://thewebservice.com/method/Service.asmx?WSDL', ['keep_alive' => false]);
$response = $client->__soapCall('method name', $parameters)
```

Comment: Yes, I experienced the same "Could not connect to host" while processing Soap requests as Laravel queue jobs. The SoapClient was using keep_alive and not closing connections but it was also creating a new connection for every job/request therefore eventually swamping the remote server. Setting keep_alive to false resolved the problem, thanks for sharing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating a new SoapClient instance for every call? In that case, disabling `keep_alive` is only a workaround and this could be improved.

SoapClient sends the HTTP Header `Connection: Keep-Alive` by default (through the constructor option `keep_alive`). But if you create a new SoapClient instance for every call in your queue, this will create and keep-open a new connection everytime. If the calls are executed fast enough, you will eventually run into a limit of 1000 open connections or so and this results in `SoapFault: Could not connect to host`.

So make sure you create the SoapClient once and reuse it for subsequent calls.